# how to iterate 20 .csv files and do some computation[the computation part,shown in code] on each and create sepaerate .scv output files in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd 
A=pd.read_csv("C:/Users/amulya/Desktop/graves lab/Mani/HIDDEN WORDS/Hidden_word_4.csv")
df1=pd.DataFrame(A)
B=pd.read_csv("C:/Users/amulya/Desktop/graves lab/words.csv")
df2=pd.DataFrame(B)
C=df1[df1.col1.isin(df2.col1)]``
df3=pd.DataFrame(C)
df3.to_csv("C:/Users/amulya/Desktop/graves lab/Mani/HIDDEN WORDS/out4.csv", encoding='utf-8', index=False)
```

## insteaad of naming the file each time, i want to iterate 20 files

Comment: There's not nearly enough information in your post to know how to answer this. What's wrong with the current code? What is "some computation"? What exactly are you stuck on? Please create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: i want to run this code for "Hidden_word_4.csv" and get output "out4.csv" like that for hidden_word 1,Hidden_word 2......till 20 and get out1,out2....till 20. Thanks!!!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.  ... http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/tutorials.html#

Comment: In a loop; construct a string for the input and output files using either string concatenation or string formatting; place your code in the loop and operate on the variables that you have assigned your strings to.

Answer (score 1):

If `df2` is static and you just want to loop through this for the 20 files, then you can make use of `os` and `re` to reduce the amount of code you need to write.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import re

path = "C:/Users/amulya/Desktop/graves lab/Mani/HIDDEN WORDS/"
df2 = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/amulya/Desktop/graves lab/words.csv")

files = [file for file in os.listdir(path) if 'Hidden_word_' in file]

for file in files:
    num = re.search('.*_(\d{1,2})', file)[1]
    df1 = pd.read_csv(path + file)
    df3 = df1[df1.col1.isin(df2.col1)]
    df3.to_csv(path+'out'+num+'.csv')
```

This assumes that the only files in your path that have `'Hidden_word_'` in their name are the ones you want to analyze, but if that's not the case, you can either modify the list creation or think about file naming and organization a bit more to facilitate things like this.